# Intraweb document collaborative editing

Tags: web-apps, collaboration

I am a big fan of Google Docs, but my workplace likes to keep internal documents internal. Is there a good **real-time** collaborative editing tool to work with .doc, .doc, .odt, or similar document formats that may be openable in Word (eventually) that we can deploy on our network? Preferably free, but we wouldn't mind a small fee. If there is a WYSIWYG (or close there to) LaTeX editor like [WriteLaTeX](https://www.writelatex.com/) that can be installed locally, that will get bonus points with me.

I like [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/), but it doesn't support more than text and html.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, It's called Microsoft Word - if you are working in .docx you probably already have it so effectively free.  MS Word can allow changes to a document by more than one user in a couple of ways - it is just:

a) the documentation sucks
 b) they keep moving where to find it
 c) they sometimes change the name

The 2 basic mechanisms are:

1. Push it out by email allowing others to add comments/ammendments - normally found in review or file/publish menus.
2. Save it to a location that everybody can see, usually a network drive, and set the document as shared.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll have to elaborate on the collaborative part, I meant real-time collaboration. Also .docx is the [Office Open XML standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) so it's not just Word (although Microsoft started it). Additionally, I've never had more formatting issues than I have in Word. However, I do not believe we own a version of Word with real-time collaboration, and I didn't think Office Web Apps was something you could install on an intranet.

Comment: .docx is a Microsoft "Open" standard, .ODT is the "Open Document Standard".  Maybe you should remove docx from your question.

Comment: Sorry, I did more research. I find it odd that Open Office can do .DOC, which is a closed format, and not .DOCX which is an "Open" format. But, yeah, I made an incorrect assumption and will edit my question.